# Table View's cellForRowAtIndexPath: not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

For some reason, my table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method isn't being called. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    chatTable = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    chatTable.delegate = self;
    chatTable.dataSource = self;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Called Count %i",messages.count);
    return messages.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Was Called");

    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    NSDictionary *message = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *mess = [message objectForKey:MSChatMessage];
    cell.textLabel.text = mess;

    return cell;
}
```

Here's what I've done:

- Linked the datasource and delgate
- Linked the IBOutlet for the table view
- Set the cell identifier to Cell
- Made sure the array was not nil (the log gives the right number)
- Tried using a static NSMutableArray, and it worked, but once i went back to my dynamic array it did not
- "Was Called" never appears in the log

Comment: your setup looks correct, to me it seems most likely that you `messages` is empty, so there is no need to the system to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`... are you sure it's not empty?

Comment: Positive, ive printed it several times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialized message:

```
messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

But then you never populated the array.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate is called based on the datasource array count.

Make sure the following line:

`NSLog(@"Called Count %i",messages.count);`

prints a count greater than 0

Comment: I didnt bother to show the code that populates the array, and it did produce 17 and not 0

Comment: @MattSarabyte ok any reason to create the table programmatically `chatTable = [[UITableView alloc]init];` try to do it with storyboards

Comment: I owe you a ton. I was using a storyboard, I have no idea why i initialized the chatTable, deleting that line made it work. Stupid mistakes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you have linked the UITableView from xib or storyboard as IBOutlet. Why are you creating the UITableView again **"chatTable = [[UITableView alloc]init]"**
Remove this line from the code and try. 
Also set the delegate and datasource from the Interface Builder and remove **chatTable.delegate = self;** & **chatTable.dataSource = self;**

Also observed that you are creating the **message** in **viewDidLoad** which is not proper. Try to **print this count of messages, it should not be zero.**

Answer (score 0):

i hop these helps..

in .h file..

```
NSMutableArray * messages;
```

in .m file..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Initialization of NSMutableArray. 
 messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

and make sure its not nil in here..

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 NSLog(@"Called Count %i",messages.count);
 return messages.count;
}
```